# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format with openweathermap api

Tags: ios, json, swift, mvvm, openweathermap

I am developing weather app in swift with openweathermap api and parse json data with mvvm pattern.I have used this code it is displaying data could not be read because it's not in the correct format.

```
import UIKit

struct WeatherModel: Codable {

    var main:String!
    var description:String!
    var icon:String!
    var temp:Int?
    
        
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case main = "main"
        case description = "description"
        case icon = "icon"
        case temp = "temp"
    }
        
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        main = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .main)
        description = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .description)
        icon = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .icon)
        temp = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .temp)
    }
}
```

This is model

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class WeatherViewModel{
    
    var modelWeather = [WeatherModel]()
    
    weak var vc: ViewController?
    
    func getWeather() {
        
        AF.request("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+(vc?.cityTextField.text)!+"&units=metric&appid=88236c7916643a06e2cd64d56f4e5077", method: .get).response{
            
            response in
            
            debugPrint(response)
            if let data = response.data
            {
                do{
                    let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherModel.self, from: data)
                    self.modelWeather.append(apiResponse)

                    debugPrint(apiResponse)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        self.vc?.reloadInputViews()
                    }
                }catch let error{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}

{"coord":{"lon":67.0822,"lat":24.9056},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":28,"feels_like":27.67,"temp_min":28,"temp_max":28,"pressure":1014,"humidity":44},"visibility":6000,"wind":{"speed":2.57,"deg":50},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1616474499,"sys":{"type":1,"id":7576,"country":"PK","sunrise":1616463159,"sunset":1616507028},"timezone":18000,"id":1174872,"name":"Karachi","cod":200}
```

This is response but error in apiresponse veriable.

Comment: Your model is wrong. Copy the response of url (E.x. view-source:http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Mumbai&units=metric&appid=88236c7916643a06e2cd64d56f4e5077) and put it at http://www.json4swift.com/ & generate your model. It will work then.

Comment: Its is generate multiple models i have used only weather and it  is still same error

Comment: Print `error` instead of `error.localizedDescription` and it will tell you exactly what the problem is

Comment: @AliAhmed : Ok, main model of below response then

{
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @FahimParkar i have get response and set into labels but image is not setting in imageview                         let iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/\(apiResponse.weather[0].icon).png"
                        self.vc?.weatherImage.image = UIImage(named: iconUrl)
this is image code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good first step is to properly model `Main`. I checked out the dummy data that was used in the comments and your `main` property is missing the nested dictionaries inside the `main` dictionary. You can map this by simply creating a struct that maps each dictionary key/value pair.

```
struct Main: Codable {
    let temp: Double
    let feels_like: Double
    let temp_min: Double
    // Continue to add the rest of the dictionaries here.
}
```

Once this is done, add this struct to your property and make it of type `Main`, like so:

`var main: Main`

Also you don't need to add `CodingKeys` unless your properties are going to be named differently than the property names that are coming back from the sever.

**EDIT**

If you wanna retrieve

```
var description:String!
var icon:String!
```

You'll need to make a `Weather` struct as well.

Hopefully this helps and you can figure out the rest of the mapping for your `WeatherModel` object.

Comment: import Foundation
struct WeatherModel : Decodable {
    let main : Main
    let weather : [Weather]
}

struct Main : Decodable {
    let temp: Double
}

struct Weather : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let main: String
    let description : String
    let icon : String
    
}

Comment: Looks great! One thing: Don't you want `WeatherModel`, `Main` & `Weather` to be `Codable`?

Comment: Now when i set in label i have found datatype error titleLabel.text = weatherModel.modelWeather[0].main.temp this is code Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'String' this is error

Comment: You have to cast `Double` to `String`

Comment: titleLabel.text = String(weatherModel.modelWeather[0].main.temp) this is code it is displaying Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range this error

Comment: Check the count for modelWeather. If it's zero, then there's a problem with your modelWeather object.

Comment: i have check this modelweather count is 0